# How to remove the padding between images and their container slides

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I am trying to remove the white space between the image and it container in the flexslide slideshow. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

I tried several ways like `itemMargin` in the init function of the slider in addition of some changes in the css flexslider.css but that doesn't help.

Edit:

My relevant code:

```
<div class="flexslider">
     <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <img src="img/02.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="img/03.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="img/04.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="img/05.jpg" />
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use inline css to style the images

Comment: Have you tried to set your images with `display: block`?

Comment: @MEM: yep, but that doesn't remove the padding in my case

Comment: hm. White space is not padding. Please post the relevant CSS.

Comment: Hi, please refer to the flexslider.css file here (I use it as it is): https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/flexslider.css